# Configure OSM Data for ArcGIS Pro Network Analysis

Tags: arcgis-pro, openstreetmap, network-analyst, general-transit-feed-specification, osmnx

I want to create a Network Dataset in ArcGIS Pro using OSM data downloaded and prepared using osmnx and python. My code is quite crude, but works so far. However, I am now transitioning to using it with public transit data, following the tutorial by ESRI.
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/networks/create-and-use-a-network-dataset-with-public-transit-data.htm

There is a step to configure the ROAD_CLASS field, which gives me a headache. ArcGIS and OSM seem to use different systems of classification. For example: in ArcGIS a roundabout is expected to consist of lines, with a "5" in the ROAD_CLASS field. However, in the OSM data the roundabout-marker is assigned to the POINT that connects the line of a street to the lines of the roundabout. The lines of the roundabout seem to be not marked as roundabout.

Is there some usual concept of dealing with this problem or official way to translate from one nomenclature to another?